# Custom view is losing some transparancy on each redraw

Tags: android, android-view, android-viewgroup

Each time my custom view is being redrawn it is losing more and more transparancy.

The code for creating the paint object:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
p.setColor(Color.argb(100, 255, 71, 126));
```

It is drawn like this:

```
canvas.drawPath(myPath, p);
```

It worsk great the first time it is drawn, however each time it is being redrawn it is losing more and more of its transparancy.. (for example when navigating away then back to the view)

The custom view is infact a ViewGroup with this code set so that it will draw itself

```
setWillNotDraw(false);
```

Thanks

Comment: You might be adding multiple of your views on top of each other. Try looking at your view hierachy

Comment: This view is currently alone in a RelativeLayout with no children

Comment: Do you add the view by xml or are you adding it programmatically?

Comment: I am adding it using xml

Answer (score 0):

Are you clearing your view inbetween draws? Otherwise, you may be drawing on top of your previous result. Drawing a translucent color over another translucent color will result in something less translucent (well, depending on your [Porter/Duff mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html)...).

Comment: I believe so. I tried to run this: `canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);` on the first line in onDraw, still same problem.